# post values from a multiselect list to a mysql query using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post, multi-select

Hi guys I am trying to post values which is getting number from another text box for MySQL select query but i am stuck can u please help me here is my code when I try to get result I cannot add comma(,) between values. also tried implode() and explode() function but the result only got number of array element please help me. I will be glad to try your ideas thanks.
on my sql query i get only row as a result which is my first select
thanks a lot for your help again guys

```
function exportselectionlist(){
var qcolumns=document.getElementById('selectionlist');
for (i=0; i < qcolumns.length; i++) {
qcolumns.options[i].selected = true;
}
document.selectionlist_form.submit();
}

<form id="selectionlist_form"  action="xxx.php" method="post"
 name="selectionlist_form">                         

    <select id="selectionlist"  style="width:300px;" multiple="multiple" size="4" 
name="selectionlist[]"> 
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="x" />
<a onclick="exportselectionlist()" href="javascript:;">Export</a>
</form>
```

//xxx.php

```
    <?php   foreach ($selectionlist as $value) {

    $resultstr = array();
foreach ($selectionlist as $result)
  $resultstr[] = $result;

echo $x=implode(",",$resultstr);

sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table where idArticle in ('$x')");
```

Comment: Did you intend for the selectionlist in your posted code to have no options?

Comment: oh thanks just realize that idiot me :) now i am trying to add comma between values still no result do u have any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your js function to:

```
function exportselectionlist() {
    var qcolumns = document.getElementById('selectionlist');
    for (i=0; i < qcolumns.length; i++) {
        qcolumns.options[i].selected = true;
    }
    document.selectionlist_form.submit();
}
```

and then your "xxx.php" to:

```
    $selectionlist = $_POST['selectionlist'];
    echo implode(',', $selectionlist);
```

As a side note, your php code indicates to me that you have register_globals turned on? I would recommend turning that off in favor of creating the variable you need from the $_POST superglobal.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help i edit code above but now i just be able asigin only one value to mysql query x just get the first value of selected list sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table where idArticle in ('$x')");

Comment: If $x is the result of the `implode($selectionlist)`, then it should work. (Granted it is not quite SAFE from SQL injection.) How are you setting $x?

Comment: now its workinh thanks i just update the code and again u r right i should improve the code to protect injection to thanks a lot again also i have one more question to when i click the link i m gettin sql error: mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in do you have any idea i think i might use if isset but my brain just stopped workin

Comment: It sounds like you are passing a boolean into mysql_num_fields. The one parameter you pass into that function should be the result of a mysql_query --> [php.net manual](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php)